# How to troubleshoot soft clutch in 1999 Ford Ranger?

Tags: ford, clutch, ranger, clutch-cylinder

I have a 1999 Ford Ranger 3.0L V6 Flex Fuel that recently had its clutch replaced.  Pilot bearing, pressure plate, slave cylinder, etc.

About 4,000 miles after the replacement the clutch started feeling very soft and I would have to "pump" up the clutch by cycling the clutch pedal a couple times every time I would start my vehicle.  It would feel right and after about 10 minutes of driving start to feel soft again.

Couple things.  I am not losing fluid.  I opened up the clutch reservoir and the fluid has not changed.  So my question is what could be causing the clutch to change how it feels while driving?

Could it be the master cylinder?